# How to iterate through an array?

Tags: python

i´m just getting started in python where I'm trying to pass some terms out of an array through a simple `for`-loop which conducts a search using a regex based pattern.

```py
ethnicities_stemms = ["religion", ["cathol", "protest"]]

for stemm in ethnicities_stemms:
    ethnicity_pattern = re.compile(r'.*'+stemm+'.*')

    ethnicity = expansions.loc[lambda x: x['queryterm'].str.contains(ethnicity_pattern, regex = True)]

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(stemm+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    ethnicity.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    writer.save()

    print(ethnicity)
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is, that the loop puts the array `religio` into the pattern and gives me all the data which contain "cathol" or "protest" and writes them together into one new `.xlsx`.

Every time I try to run the code, the error message `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str` prompts.

Comment: Try changing `ethnicities_stemms = ["religion", ["cathol", "protest"]]` to `ethnicities_stemms = ["religion", "cathol", "protest"]` and see if you get the same error

Comment: Why does the title mention iteration, when the error doesn't seem to be related to that? Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: well no, but thats not the solution to my problem. Now it runs through but writes the data for "cathol" and "protest" into two unique excel-sheets but I would like to achieve that it writes both into one sheet named religion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the second item in your list is another list (`["cathol", "protest"]`), which cannot be added to a string (as you try to do in `re.compile(r'.*'+stemm+'.*')`). I would guess you might be trying to do something like this - which creates an Excel Workbook called 'religion' with sheets called 'cathol' and 'protest'.

```
ethnicities_stemms = {"religion": ["cathol", "protest"]}

for key, value in ethnicities_stemms.items():
    # key is 'religion' and value is ['cathol', 'protest']
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(key +'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    for stemm in value:
        ethnicity_pattern = re.compile(r'.*'+stemm+'.*')
        ethnicity = expansions.loc[lambda x: x['queryterm'].str.contains(ethnicity_pattern, regex = True)]
        ethnicity.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=stemm, index=False)
        print(ethnicity)
    writer.save()
```

You can then add other key-list pairs to your dictionary.

Comment: Thank you! But sadly it just writes the data of "protest" into the sheet and ignores "cathol"

Comment: That's because they write over each other in the same sheet. However I have just edited so it creates separate sheets. if you want both tables on one sheet you will have to position them by choosing an appropriate `startrow` for `to_excel`

Comment: I`m so sorry you absolutely achieved what I was looking for it creates two sheets in one xlsx. Thank you so much!!